# Need top 5 searched keywords from sum of searched words

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, sum

| Category | Searched Word | Search Count | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clothing | Men Shirt | 3544 | 2022-01-19 |
| Footwear | Shoes | 7293 | 2022-02-02 |
| Mobile | Iphone | 4901 | 2022-02-12 |
| Clothing | Hoodie | 2049 | 2021-12-30 |
| Footwear | crocs | 3328 | 2022-01-28 |
| Clothing | Men shirt | 903 | 2022-02-12 |

I am working on bigquery and from above table I need to find top 5 searched word for each category on the basis of sum of search count column between date 2022-01-01 to 2022-02-14, I have tried SQL windows function but couldn't solve. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any of below approaches

Option 1

```
select Category, string_agg(SearchedWord, ', ' order by totalCount desc limit 5) topFiveSearchedWord
from (
  select Category, initcap(SearchedWord) SearchedWord, sum(SearchCount) totalCount
  from your_table
  where date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-02-14'
  group by Category, SearchedWord
)
group by Category
```

Option 2

```
select Category, 
  ( select string_agg(value, ', ' order by sum desc)
    from t.arr
  ) topFiveSearchedWord
from (
  select Category, approx_top_sum(initcap(SearchedWord), SearchCount, 5) Arr
  from your_table
  where date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-02-14'
  group by Category            
) t
```